# Unable to Debug in GoLand IDE : could not launch process: can not run under Rosetta

Tags: go, ide, goland

Hi New here to Go Language.
I have indtalled go and have downloaded GoLand. I was able to run the code successfully. However when i try to debug the code its showing the following error

> could not launch process: can not run under Rosetta, check that the
> installed build of Go is right for your CPU architecture

My Go Version is : go version go1.17.8 darwin/arm64
Device details : [image]

What should i do to resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you installed GoLand for Apple Silicon architecture from https://www.jetbrains.com/go/download/?

Answer (score -1):

```
  # build new dlv
   git clone https://github.com/go-delve/delve.git
   cd delve/cmd/dlv
   go build 
   go install 
  
   cd $GOPATH/bin
   mkdir macarm
   cp ./dlv ./macarm/
```

```
 ### config goland ide 
 menu: help -> edit Coustom Properties   
 input : dlv.path=$GOPATH/bin
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).